# How can I store a selectInput in a vector?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to save a selectInput in a vector.

In my UI I've got:

```
selectInput("my_ID", "Search for a name", unique(datatable$names), "Henry")
```

In my server, I want to save this input in a variable to use it later.

This is basically what I want:

```
selectedNames <- input$my_ID
```

Of course, this does not work.
So I tried this:

```
selectedNames <- reactive(input$my_ID)
```

But I get this warning again:

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :    Operation not
>   allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something
>   that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

I have also tried to do it with an observer and different chunks of code I found on the internet, but nothing worked.

At the end, I want to use the selectedNames is a filter like this:

```
example <- datatable %>% filter(names %in% selectedNames())
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `selectedNames <- reactive({input$my_ID})`

Then use `selectedNames()` in the rest of the app.

See [Reactivity - An overview](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html).

**Update**

Working Test Example:

```
library(shiny)

datatable <- data.frame(names = c('Henry', 'Charles', 'Robert', 'William'))

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("my_ID", "Search for a name", unique(datatable$names), "Henry")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    selectedNames <- reactive({input$my_ID})

    observeEvent(req(selectedNames()), {
        example <- datatable %>% filter(names %in% selectedNames())
        print(example)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You don't really need the reactive and could just use `input$my_ID` directly, as below:

```
library(shiny)

datatable <- data.frame(names = c('Henry', 'Charles', 'Robert', 'William'))

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("my_ID", "Search for a name", unique(datatable$names), "Henry")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(req(input$my_ID), {
        example <- datatable %>% filter(names %in% input$my_ID)
        print(example)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Nope. I tried this as well. I just did not include the {} in my question.

Comment: What error does that give? We need a min reprex to really help you.